# Floating element overlapping the main page content

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've a footer styled with CSS which floats at the bottom of the page but when I re-size browser window my footer overlaps my page contents footer is quit big though but it should not overlay the page content.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #64aba7;
}
strong {
  color: #fff
}
.container {
  min-height: 500px;
}
.header {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.header,
img {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.content {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
}
.green-color {
  color: #25b04b;
}
.dark-green {
  color: #016838;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: #00756f;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.footer-container {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 500px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.font-size-12px {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #64aba7;
  font-weight: 50;
}
.one-third {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="images/logo-large.png" alt="LegalHQ">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="green-color">We are redevloping our website and will be back shortly</h3>
    <h4 class="dark-green"><i>In the meantime don't hesitate to call or email us</i></h4>
    <p class="dark-green">0330 999 1213
      <br /><a href="mailto:hello@legal-hq.co.uk">hello@legal-hq.co.uk</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-container">
      <div class="one-third img-div">
        <img src="images/small-logo.gif" alt="LegalHQ">
      </div>
      <div class="one-third font-size-12px">
        <strong>Legal HQ Limited</strong>
        <br />Virginia House
        <br />Floor 2
        <br />5-7 Great Ancoats Street
        <br />Manchester
        <br />M4 5AD
        <br />0161 974 0500
        <br />
        <a href="mailto:support@legal-hq.co.uk">support@legal-hq.co.uk</a>
        <br />
        <a href="www.legal-hq.co.uk">www.legal-hq.co.uk</a>
      </div>
      <div class="one-third font-size-12px">
        <strong>Legal HQ Limited</strong> is regulated by the Ministry of Justice in respect of regulated claims management activities. <strong>Authorisation Number: CRM30929</strong> 
        <a href="www.claimsregulation.gov.uk">www.claimsregulation.gov.uk</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kscfbbxL/2/) if you want to experience it yourself. Try and re-size the browser window to the point where you would see footer overlapping the main content.

Comment: Can't reproduce it. I'm able to reduce the width to aproximately 200px and still able to see the main content.

Comment: Looks fine to me in Chrome.

Comment: I can reproduce it on Firefox. @TIMINeutron The problem appears if you reduce the height, not the width.

Comment: Producing a jsfiddle.net with the minimum code required to reproduce the issue would be the best way for us to see the problem. External sites can be changed at any time.

Comment: @anothershrubery jsfiddle is an external site.  The minimum code should be posted here, especially with the new code snippet feature.  Links to jsfiddle are just a useful extra

Comment: Well yes, he has produced code and put it here, that wasn't my point. If you are going to provide a link to a site, a link to jsfiddle is hugely preferred than a random external site that could change numerous times a day and may not reflect the actual problem if someone looks at this question months down the line. Using jsfiddle means the code will always be the same and it gives developers an easy way to tinker and spot errors.

Comment: @anothershrubery jsfiddle added :)

Comment: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 1):

give the html,body height of 100%, get the footer out of the container, remove position absolute, remove floats from the div-children, and add display:inline-block to them and give them widths of 28% (or remove whitespaces between them) (or otherwise you should use text-align:center for container...but that's another story)

Comment: no this does not works after removing position:absolute my footer now under the container box

Comment: That's because you didn't change the other things as well...I did this in firebug and it worked like a charm.